# nginx as proxy multiple vhosts

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008, nginx, virtualhost

Runing Windows Server 2008 R2

nginx on port 8080
Apache on port 80

Apache is hosting 5 websites configured within the  directive.

I'm trying to configure nginx as proxy in front of Apache, (I'll reverse the port numbers after done testing).

nginx.conf includes this server,

```
    server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  www.domain1.com;

    root   PATH/domain1/;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
           expires 365d;
        }

    ## send request back to apache1 ##
    location / {
     proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1;
     proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
     proxy_redirect off;
     proxy_buffering off;
     proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
     proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   }
}server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  www.domain2.com;

    root   PATH/domain2/;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;

    ## send request back to apache1 ##
    location / {
     proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1;
     proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
     proxy_redirect off;
     proxy_buffering off;
     proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
     proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   }
}
```

It works, but If I add a second server, the second server will result in 404 error because nginx is still trying to locate the content for the second site within the site1 folder.

What is the proper way to configure multiple websites on nginx? (Windows).

Comment: `If I add a second server` If you post the vhost conf for the second server too, that may help someone to help you!

Answer (score 0):

first guess: did you restarted/reloaded your nginx after changing the config?

you config looks ok so far; i'd include a separate `access_log /path/to/domainX_access.log` directive into each server {} - part for better debugging; at least you'll know from the logs, which virtual-host is met.

Comment: Of course, nginx -s reload, I have a main log file, and all requests are being sent to the first server, and there for resulting in error 404, 403 for when trying to load the second server.

Comment: 404 -> your root /path/to/files; is not correct or the files are really not there; usually the logs are teling the truth :)

Comment: 403: no access to files or directories in root /../; path, if not otherwise protected; check your permissions on given path, if the webserver-user can access every level.

Comment: ah, windows, dont know how to set the right path ... c:/blah/blieh/blupp?

Comment: Wwhat should the path/to/files; be? shouldn't it be the same as Apache's vhosts pathes?

Comment: the path to your docroot, where you serve files from, if so. if not, this is a total apache-problem, because the errors the come from apache who isnt able to read its docroot.

Comment: But Apache is serving correct files for each domain when accessed directly. In face Apache is in production right now and serving content on those domains without issues.

Comment: ok; longer answer will follow.